# Does S3 multipart upload actually create multiple objects in my bucket?

Tags: file-io, amazon-s3, filesystems

Here is an example for me trying to understand the under the hood mechanism.

I decide to upload a 2GB file onto my S3 bucket, and I decide to use the size of 128MB for the parts. Then I will have

```
(2 * 1024) / 128 => 16 parts
```

**Here are my questions:**

- Am I going to see 16 128MB objects in my bucket or a single 2GB
  object in my bucket?
- How can S3 understand the order of the parts (1->2->...->16) and
  reassemble them into a single 2GB file when I download them back? Is
  there an extra 'meta' object (see the above question) that I need to download first to help the client to achieve this reassembling-needed information?
- When the s3 client download the above in parallel, at what time does it write the file descriptor for this 2GB file in the local file system (I guess it does not know all the needed information before all the parts have been downloaded)?

Answer (score 1):

While uploading the individual parts, there will be multiple **uploads** stored in Amazon S3 that you can view with the `ListMultipartUploads` command.

When completing a multipart upload with the `CompleteMultipartUpload` command, you must specify a list of the individual parts uploaded in the correct order. The uploads will then be combined into a single **object**.

Downloading depends upon the client/code you use -- you could download an object in parallel or just single-threaded.